# How to implement Entity Reference, Objects and CRUD operations?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to create an object, named **XML**. The XML object has a name(string) and the content itself (in XML format).

CRUD operations should be supported as follows:

- I want to make each user able to **C**reate, **U**pdate, and **D**elete instances of the XML object.
- These instances can only be seen (**R**ead) by their owner.

I also want to be able to programatically do some **actions** with the data before they are saved, deleted, etc.

Any advice about how to do so?